# List running threads of an external process

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

Sometimes we have "ghost" application by our customers(meaning that when we close the application after a lot of time(like 72+ hours), we have, sometimes the application that is visually closed but still in the process list.

Since we can't reproduce easily, we would like to know which thread is still running. So we would like to provide a very small tools, in which we can select a process(select the one that is a "ghost"), and then display all information that we can get (Threads names that are running mostly).

So:

1. Is this possible ? I don't know if a c# application can access to
   the thread name of another application?
2. Is there any existing application that can do this kind of "extraction"
3. what should we use to access this kind of informations?

Comment: Is this a third party application? I.e. one you have no control over?

Comment: Some, other not, e.g. we already found once a thread that was blocked by windows when disposing a socket which was having a full queue

Comment: No, we develop this application, but we don't want to put this tools IN the application, since: the problem happens when we are closing the application, and we don't want to add more threads, and we would like to have a diagnose software.

Comment: Ok I was just thinking that with your own applications it should always be possible to ensure all background threads are closed before the GUI (main) thread exits. Our own app had this problem until I made sure all the background threads were closed properly, even after an exception.

Comment: @Surfbutler, yeah that would be the best, but we currently do not have a centralized "manager" that knows all the thread we are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Justin Harvey mentioned, Process explorer is a good solution.

If you wish to provide your own tool, you could be interrested in :

[Process.GetProcessByName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/725c3z81%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and [Process.Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx)

Usage

```
var process = Process.GetProcessByName("myprocess").FirstOrDefault();
var threads = process.Threads;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try process explorer, this will show details of the threads within a running process:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

[image: Process Explorer Threads]

Comment: Is there any way to have more information on the thread? Because I don't know if I can extract the position in my code with the StartAddress, if not I'm not sure of how I can use it for my current problem

Answer (score 1):

While you can access threading information of another process as such:

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("YourProcess");
foreach (ProcessThread thread in p[0].Threads)
{
    Console.WriteLine(thread.Id);
}
```

You **can not** access the name of the thread, but you can retrieve the information available in the [ProcessThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx) class.